# Interpolating data in 1D with 2D sample points and a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, vectorization, interpolation

I have a matrix of Temperatures ( **T - [120xN]**  ) at different heights ( **H - [120xN]** ).
I want to obtain the Temperatures at a set vector of heights ( **Hnew - [100x1]** ], where N is the total number of lines I want to independently interpolate in 1D.

I can solve this with a loop quite easily

```
Tnew = zeros(length(Hnew),N);
for i-1:N
   Tnew(:,i) = interp1(H(:,i),T(:,i),Hnew);
end
```

But since I have many iterations to perform (N ~ 2 million), I am looking for a solution without a loop.

What is the optimum way to do this in matlab?

Comment: Are the columns in H different? Or were the heights all sampled at the same locations? For example, are H(:,1) and H(:,N) the same? If so, you can simply use `Tnew = interp1(H(:,1),T,Hnew);` and skip the for loop altogether. You could also group columns by repeated height columns which would reduce the number of iterations.

Comment: The H columns are all different, only the Hnew are the same

Comment: The problem is that you'll need a new interpolant function, `t = f(h)` for each column. While it may not be desirable to you, your for-loop approach is probably the best option. You could, of course, have a look on the mathworks file exchange site for faster interpolation options. For example, you could replace `interp1` with [`lininterp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28376-faster-linear-interpolation) or [`reduce_linear_interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52552-fast-reducing-of-sample-points-for-1d-linear-interpolation).